# How do you simplify these loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def funny_phrases(list):

    funny = []
    for word1 in list:
        if len(word1) >= 6:
            funny.append(word1)

    phrases = []
    for word2 in funny:
        if word2[-1:] is "y":
            phrases.append(word2)
    return phrases


print(funny_phrases(["absolutely", "fly", "sorry", "taxonomy", "eighty", "excellent"]))
print(funny_phrases(["terrible", "normally", "naughty", "party"]))
print(funny_phrases(["tour", "guy", "pizza"]))
```

I have these loops and was wondering if there were any ways to simplify it.

Comment: This isn't a nested loop. It's two loops, with neither nested in the other.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I edited the title and body to address this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Test both conditions at once to reduce it to one loop:

```
def funny_phrases(lst):
    funny = []
    for word in lst:
        if len(word) >= 6 and word.endswith('y'):
            funny.append(word)
    return funny
```

which can then be translated to a list comprehension, leaving:

```
def funny_phrases(lst):
    return [word for word in lst if len(word) >= 6 and word.endswith('y')]
```

Note that I made two small changes beyond the loop improvements:

1. I changed the variable name to `lst` to avoid name-shadowing the `list` constructor (which would have prevented you from using it if you ever needed it)
2. I changed slicing with magic numbers to the named method `.endswith('y')`, which is more self-documenting (and doesn't require temporary `str`s, like slicing would).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using nested loop, but you could use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
def funny_phrases(words):
    funny = filter(lambda word: len(word) >= 6, words)
    return list(filter(lambda word: word[-1:] is "y", funny))
```

By the way, as you can see I renamed your parameter `list` to `words` because it was overriding the [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function. Try to not call `list` to your lists, instead use more explaining names.

Or in one line:

```
def funny_phrases(words):
    return list(filter(lambda word: word[-1:] is "y", filter(lambda word: len(word) >= 6, words)))
```

Or doing a single iteration:

```
def funny_phrases(words):
    return list(filter(lambda word: len(word) >= 6 and word[-1:] is "y", words))
```

Or if you prefer list comprehensions:

```
def funny_phrases(words):
    return [word for word in words if len(word) >= 6 and word[-1:] is "y"]
```

In addition, somethings can be improved:

```
word[-1:] is "y"
```

That isn't good, instead:

```
word.endswith("y")
```

That is more verbose and easier to understand.

So your final could should be one of both:

```
def funny_phrases(words):
    return [word for word in words if len(word) >= 6 and word.endswith("y")]

def funny_phrases(words):
    return list(filter(lambda word: len(word) >= 6 and word.endswith("y"), words))
```

I would use list comprehension because they are more verbose in my opinion, but that is up to you.

As [@ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) commented, list comprehension are a rather better choice for this task. They look better and in this case (using lambda) they are faster than `filter`.

Comment: Note: `map`/`filter` are only an improvement over equivalent list comprehensions or generator expressions when the transform/predicate function is a built-in implemented in C. If `map`/`filter` need a `lambda` that the listcomp/genexpr could avoid, they're *always* slower, and usually uglier, as you can see comparing the two in your answer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, well, that is why I always prefer list comprehension :)!

Comment: Also, to be clear, list comprehensions *are* a functional programming construct. `map`/`filter` are neither more nor less functional; they're all functional programming tools. If people claim to prefer `filter` for being more "functional", they don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, about that part I can't say anything because I don't know about functional programming, I just was repeating what some (wrong) people told me.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def funny_phrases(list):
    return [(l) for l in list if len(l)>6 and l[len(l)-1] == 'y']

print(funny_phrases(["absolutely", "fly", "sorry", "taxonomy", "eighty", "excellent"]))

['absolutely', 'taxonomy']
```